# Cannot change attributes of dependency configuration ':app:releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath' after it has been resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I upgraded my gradle from 7.0.4 to 7.2.1 on prompt from android studio. Android Studio ran upgrade assisstant to upgrade the gradle and immediately after it began gradle sync and after that I get the

> Cannot change attributes of dependency configuration
> ':app:releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath'after it has been resolved

[image]

This is what my build window shows
[image]

I am unable to figure out this error. What does ':app:releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath' means?

Comment: did you figure this out? I am also getting the same error.

Comment: @Paragon Nope, can't find any solution

Comment: @SakshamPruthi have you got the fix of it. Having same problem here

Comment: @Mayur Couldn't find a fix for it and ended up degrading the Gradle back to make things work

Comment: @SakshamPruthi I had got a fix but it may be project specific. Do you use hilt in your project?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. It was this code:

```
project.tasks.withType(Test::class.java) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        setEvents(setOf("passed", "skipped", "failed"))
    }
}
```

I replace it with this:

```
project.tasks.withType(Test::class.java).configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        setEvents(setOf("passed", "skipped", "failed"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your post has been really useful for me